# Comparing tokens of string with tokens of array of strings

Tags: arrays, regex, perl, substring

I have a string containing a list of whitespace-separated tokens.

```
my $string = "--configure-option1 --configure-option2 --configure-option3 --configure-option4";
```

I have an array of similar strings.

```
my @array = (
   "--configure-option20",
   "--configure-option2 --configure-option5",
   "--configure-option10 --configure-option11",
   "--configure-option15 --configure-option22 --configure-option27",
);
```

I'd like to determine if any of the tokens in `$string` are also found in one of the strings in `@array`.For example, the result is true for the above values since both `$string` and `$array[1]` contain the token `--configure-option2`.

Comment: @ ikegami Is that a better title for the question?

Comment: Don't write `[some failed configure]` as an example, if that is what it is. Write exactly how the string appears.

Comment: This also appears to be an XY-problem. Share some insight into what you are doing and why.

Comment: @ikegami Because if he is parsing a string, it would be nice to know what the string actually looks like?

Comment: The test "Any substring of string1 matches any substring of string2" can be simplified to `1` (true), as `"" eq ""` is true for any string1 and string2.

Comment: I see what you are asking now that I have worked my way through the text. You are parsing configuration options, and if any option that is listed in the `@Failures` array appears in the current string you are parsing, you want to exclude that string. I would have to say that the simplest way to do that would be to first parse the options, using whatever method you are using to do that.

Comment: For example, if you have a sub `parse_cfg` that returns a hash, use that on the string to get the values, then compare the key/value pairs, using the `@Failures` array as the loop condition.

Comment: Do you see that your specification is incorrect? You ask for *any substring of string1 matches any substring of string2*. The letter `n` is a substring of `$array[$element]`, and it is also a substring of *every* element of `@Failures`, but I doubt if that is what you mean

Comment: Please can you change your data examples to compilable Perl. For example the output if `Data::Dumper`

Comment: You're asking for "whitespace-delimited substrIngs". I suggest you fix your question, and include some compilable data as I said

Comment: @Kaleb Perl strings aren't terminated by `\0`, and `\0` is not whitespace (also, every string is itself a string).

Comment: @Kaleb Would `--configure-option1="foo"` be equal to `--configure_option1=foo`?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl


my @pairs = (
    '--configure-option1 --configure-option2 --configure-option3 --configure-option4',
    '--configure-option3 --configure-option4 --configure-option12',
);

my @failures = (
    '--configure-option20',
    '--configure-option2 --configure-option5',
    '--configure-option10 --configure-option11',
    '--configure-option15 --configure-option22 --configure-option27',
);

$all = 0;
$size = $#pairs + 1;
my $string1;
my $string2;

while ($all < $size) {
##... Other code happening here
## Begin test case
####################################################

        # loop through the existing failure cases. Logic here is that
        # the failures array will always be < the build array.
        # (the full build array has thousands of options while the
        # failures array can not possibly grow larger than that and
        # ideally will be much smaller than that.
        foreach $string1 (@failures) {

            $string2 = $pairs[$all];

            # get string1 from the Failures array and parse it up into the
            # @compare1 array
            # get string2 from the current configure option and parse it into
            # @compare2 array

            my @compare1 = split(' ', $string1);
            my @compare2 = split(' ', $string2);

            # loop through both arrays storing each element in var1 and var2
            # for comparing
            foreach my $var1 (@compare1) {
                foreach my $var2 (@compare2) {

                    #see if var1 and var2 match
                    if ($var1 eq $var2) {
                        print "ALERT!!!!\n";
                        print "string1 is: \"$string1\"\n";
                        print "string2 is: \"$string2\"\n\n";
                        print "found match string1 contains $var1 and string2 contains $var2\n\n";
                        $reject = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if ($reject eq 1) {
            print "\n$string2\n";
            print "didn't run this test because it's been rejected\n\n";

            # reset the reject flag
            $reject = 0;
        }
        else {
            print "\n$string2\n";
            print "This test did run\n\n";
        }

        $all = $all + 1;
####################################################
## End test case
##... Rest of script
}
```

Output from Run:

```
ALERT!!!!
string1 is: "--configure-option2 --configure-option5"
string2 is: "--configure-option1 --configure-option2 --configure-option3 --configure-option4"

found match string1 contains --configure-option2 and string2 contains --configure-option2


--configure-option1 --configure-option2 --configure-option3 --configure-option4
didn't run this test because it's been rejected


--configure-option3 --configure-option4 --configure-option12
This test did run
```

Comment: None of the solutions provided worked out as intended in the final script. Sinan yours was close but I couldn't make it quite work. Thanks for your submission though. @ikegami your's worked to get the first match however everything after that would also report a match even when there was no match. This is what I ended up working out on my own. It works but is probably far from optimal. If you have any optimization suggestions please contribute. Regards, Kaleb

Comment: @ikegami Additionally thank you for cleaning up my question. I apologize for my initial lack of clarity on the issue. It is difficult for me to express in words what is going on in my mind. I will try to get better at this in the future.

Comment: Re "your's worked to get the first match however everything after that would also report a match even when there was no match. " This makes absolutely no sense. As requested, it only checks if there is a match. It doesn't get any matches, so it can't possibly get the first match right and the later matches wrong.

Comment: Re "It is difficult for me to express in words", Then don't use words. If you were the provide all the necessary info (your inputs, your code, your desired output, and your obtained output), further description is almost uneccessary.

Comment: Re "If you have any optimization suggestions please contribute.", Your solution scales insanely badly. I've already provided optimized solutions to the question asked.

Answer (score 4):

```
my $alt = join '|', map quotemeta, split ' ', $string;
my $re = qr/(?<!\S)(?:$alt)(?!\S)/;

my $match = grep /$re/, @array;
```

To speed things up some:

```
my $match = join(' ', @array) =~ /$re/;
```

To speed things up more, and to save memory:

```
my $match = 0
for (@array) {
   if (/$re/) {
      $match = 1;
      last;
   }
}
```

Comment: No in fact it is not I need to match this "--configure-option2"

from [--configure-option2 --configure-option5] and [--configure-option10 --configure-option2]

Comment: You may as well just write `my $escaped_chars = quotemeta($string1)` and let the regex engine sort it out

Comment: @Borodin Thank you for some constructive advice. I will try that and upvote if it works.

Comment: @Kaleb It's not a good idea to ask people to stop helping just because you don't understand what they are saying or asking. Try to answer the questions and give relevant feedback and your question will be answered faster. With relevant info, a question can usually be answered in minutes. In the case where the OP does not understand how to ask, the answer is delayed, and sometimes never comes.

Comment: @Kaleb: It won't work - it does the same as ikegami wrote, and I described in my comment on your question

Comment: @TLP Thank You for constructive criticism. I will take it to heart.

Comment: @TLP:The problem isn't that Kaleb doesn't understand what is being said. On the contrary, I believe he is quite clear that ikegami's post is a useless joke about the shortcomings of the question

Comment: Updated my answer to match the latest incarnation of the question.

Answer (score 2):

I think this goes some way to solving your problem if I have guessed your data format correctly

It converts the `@failures` array into a hash containing all of the different options that should cause a rejection if they appear. Then it works through the `@array` (your name, not mine!) and uses `grep` to check whether any of the constituent options appears in the `%failures` hash, and prints the result

If speed is an issue then you may want to replace `grep` with `any` from `List::MoreUtils`

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my @array = (
    '--configure-option1 --configure-option2 --configure-option3 --configure-option4',
    '--configure-option3 --configure-option4 --configure-option12',
);

my @failures = (
    '--configure-option20',
    '--configure-option2 --configure-option5',
    '--configure-option10 --configure-option11',
    '--configure-option15 --configure-option22 --configure-option27',
);

my %failures;
$failures{$_} = 1 for map split, @failures;

for my $options ( @array ) {
    my $reject = grep { $failures{$_} } split ' ', $options;
    say $options, '  ', $reject ? 'FAIL' : 'PASS';
}
```

#### output

```
--configure-option1 --configure-option2 --configure-option3 --configure-option4  FAIL
--configure-option3 --configure-option4 --configure-option12  PASS
```

Comment: While `any` is better than `grep`, it's still O(N). If you want to optimized version of this, you'd use my earlier answer. Actually, you'd build a regex instead of splitting.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is far from clear. Based on what I can read between the lines, I came up with this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Set::CrossProduct;

my $x = '[--configure-option1 --configure-option2 --configure-option3 --configure-option4]';

my $y = '[--configure-option20][--configure-option2 --configure-option5][--configure-option10 --configure-option11][--configure-option15 --configure-option22 --configure-option27]';

my $pat = qr/([a-z0-9-]+)/;

my @x = ($x =~ /$pat/g);
my @y = ($y =~ /$pat/g);

my $it = Set::CrossProduct->new([\@x, \@y]);
while (my $el = $it->get) {
    if ($el->[0] eq $el->[1]) {
        printf "'%s' appears in both\n", $el->[0];
    }
}
```

Output:

```
C:\...\Temp> perl tt.pl
'--configure-option2' appears in both
```